# SSLHandshake while calling calling external web service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, ssl, jaxb

When i try to call an external web service using WebServiceTemplate i get the error :

> {"timestamp":1578564474835,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException","message":"I/O error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching www.test-test.com found.; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching www.test-test.com found.","path":"/mycall/test"}

And this is my code for the call:

```
    ....
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("wsdl");
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(wsdlUrl);
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    JAXBElement<MyClass> res = (JAXBElement<MyClass>)  
    webServiceTemplate
            .marshalSendAndReceive(wsdlUrl, xClass);
    ....
```

Thank you

Comment: "No subject alternative DNS name matching www.test-test.com found." The certificate the remote side presents doesn't match the name that you use to contact that site.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Indeed you are right i've called them to fix that, Thank you.